# Error while trying to access the remote Server IIS WebSites Names

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I am trying to access the WebSite Names in IIS-7 Web Server from a Remote Machine.
Following is are the details while trying to use the below mentioned code.

**Error Message**

The RPC server is unavailable.

**Code**

```
string path = "IIS://ServerName/W3SVC";

using (DirectoryEntry w3svc = new DirectoryEntry(path, "UserName", "Password"))
{
    foreach (DirectoryEntry entry in w3svc.Children)
    {
        if (entry.SchemaClassName == "IIsWebServer")
        {
            string websiteName = (string)entry.Properties["ServerComment"].Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the client machine and the server are both Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008 or greater, please make sure that in both machines *IIS Metabase and IIS 6 configuration compatibility* is on.

You can check and adjust the setting if necessary in:

Windows Vista or greater:

Control Panel –> Programs and Features –> Turn Windows Features on or off –>  Internet Information Services –> Web Management tools –> IIS 6 Management Compatibility –> IIS Metabase and IIS 6 configuration compatibility

Windows Server 2008 or greater:

Server Manager –> Roles –> Web Server (IIS) –> Add Role Services  –> Management Tools –> IIS 6 Management Compatibility –> Select IIS 6 Metabase compatibility, IIS 6 WMI compatibility and IIS 6 Scripting Tools.

If you prefer not to install this component on both client and server sides, you can change your code to use the *IIS Management API* available through the *Microsoft.Web.Administration* library. The piece of code you will need to perform the task you describe would be this one:

```
ServerManager serverManager = ServerManager.OpenRemote("your-server-name");    
Site site = serverManager.Sites.Where(s => s.Name == "Default Web Site").FirstOrDefault();
string webSiteName = site.Name;
```

Comment: But you are trying to access your IIS 7 through Directory Services API, which needs an ADSI provider installed on client and server machine. In order to make IIS 7 accesible through this API you need to have installed "IIS Metabase and IIS 6 configuration compatibility". If you don´t want to install this component on both client and server sides, you should change your code to use the IIS Management API available through the Microsoft.Web.Administration library.

Comment: Can you give some sample code for this Microsoft.Web.Administration library

Comment: Please take a look at the link I have posted in my edited answer.

Comment: This will not help because it is extracting info from local server not remote server

Comment: I forgot to mention that with ServerManager you have the OpenRemote static method which allows you to manage a remote IIS machine. Please take a look at the piece of code included in the updated answer